# Invalid token information returned by describe_ring: {}

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

I am trying to use CassandraStorage in pig, and I am getting the error "Invalid token information returned by describe_ring: {}" whenever I try to output to Cassandra. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: How are you outputting it?  We can't tell what is wrong until you provide the code that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your cassandra cluster/keyspace is not set properly. Try to enable debug logs and see exact Exception